# What tool is best for removing pages from a password protected PDF?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, leopard

I have a set of PDF documents that each have a few extra pages. I'd like to remove the first two and last pages from each of them. Preview only lets me look at and annotate a PDF, not edit one. Can anyone recommend a (free/freeware) tool to do this? I'm using 10.5 PPC so that does limit some of my options. Command line or GUI is fine.

---

Ok, in Preview it seems I can delete pages by hitting <kbd>⌘⌫</kbd> on the thumbnails, but it will then not give me the option to save. I can then try printing the altered document to PDF, but I am leery of this because I don't want to loose any metadata (I have to double-check all the files to see how much metadata there is if I decide on this course).

---

Just tried Acrobat at work, that doesn't work. The files are mod-protected by a password.

Comment: Preview on 10.6 Snow Leopard and 10.7 Lion will let you edit PDFs and save them in this fashion.

Comment: Maybe your PDFs are protected, that's why Preview refuses to offer saving the modified files.

Comment: Preview in Lion is saving the files automatically, isn't it?

Comment: Preview can cut pages in a PDF if allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Preview can selectively export pages of a PDF through the printing options. I just download IRS form W9, which has four pages. The first page is the form that needs to be filled out, and the final three pages are instructions. I filled out the first page using Preview on Mountain Lion, then I chose to print. From the print screen, I chose to include only one page (the first page), and saved to PDF with the button at the bottom of the print sheet. This technique can be used for individual pages or a range of pages.

Comment: **+1** Selective Export and Merge works like a breeze with **Preview**

Answer (score 4):

For the command-line I can recommend:

[pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), the PDF Toolkit (for the Snow-Leopard installer you can try [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) to get the binaries or use the older version)

> Merge PDF Documents
>
> Split PDF Pages into a New Document
>
> Rotate PDF Pages or Documents
>
> …

If your PDF is edit-protected, you may want to try [qpdf](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) ([via](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/qpdf) e.g. [homebrew](https://brew.sh)) to remove the restrictions first.

> QPDF is a command-line program that does structural, content-preserving transformations on PDF files. It could have been called something like pdf-to-pdf. It also provides many useful capabilities to developers of PDF-producing software or for people who just want to look at the innards of a PDF file to learn more about how they work.

Comment: It's going to take some work for me to figure out how to build it (127 errors!)

Comment: I couldn't find a binary for qpdf with a quick search - but qpdf is also available via [Macports](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/textproc/qpdf/Portfile) or [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/qpdf). Maybe you got better luck trying one of these packet-managers to install/build qpdf

Comment: I just found an older version (2.2.2) of qpdf as universal binary here: http://r.research.att.com/libs/

Answer (score 4):

As I have written [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf/672001#672001), [QPDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPDF) is great. Use it this way to extract pages 3-998 from 1000 pages of `input.pdf` and save it as `output.pdf`.

```
qpdf --pages input.pdf 3-998 -- input.pdf output.pdf
```

Please note that `input.pdf` is written twice.

You can install as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956875/how-can-i-install-qpdf-on-mac-10-8-3):

Download [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and invoke:

```
sudo port install qpdf
```

Or you can install it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install qpdf
```

It is a great tool for PDF manipulation, which is very fast, has very few dependencies. "It can encrypt and linearize files, expose the internals of a PDF file, and do many other operations useful to end users and PDF developers."

http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/

It can work with password protected files. For example:

```
qpdf --empty --copy-encryption=encrypted.pdf --encryption-file-password=pass
--pages encrypted.pdf --password=pass 1 ./encrypted.pdf --password=pass 1 --
outfile.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

[PDFpen from Smile Software](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/index.html) is a commercial program that can do this and much more. The latest version for Lion is PDFpen 5.8, but you can purchase a copy of their [older version 4.7.1](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/faq.html), which is compatible with 10.5 Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

The commandline for **pdftk** (suggested by iolsmit) to remove the first 2 and the last two pages from a 30-page PDF named `input1.pdf` is this:

```
pdftk \
  input1.pdf \
  cat 3-28 \
  output input1_p3-28.pdf
```

The very latest, still unreleased version of Ghostscript (which will become v. 9.06 in a few weeks) can also do it:

```
gs \
  -o input1_p3-28.pdf \
  -dFirstPage=3 \
  -dLastPage=28 \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   input1.pdf
```

To automatically determine the number of pages, you could use `pdfinfo` (also available from MacPorts):

```
pdfinfo input1.pdf
```

will show the collection of embedded metadata about the PDF. Hence you could script the whole process of removing the pages. First, put the number of pages into a variable:

```
_endpage=$(( $(pdfinfo input1.pdf | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}' sed 's# ##g') - 2 ))
```

Then, run one of the above commandlines using this variable:

```
pdftk input1.pdf cat 3-${_endpage} output input1_p3-${_endpage}.pdf
```

Just put these two lines into a Bash script called `remove-my-4-pages.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
_endpage=$(( $(pdfinfo ${1}.pdf | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}' sed 's# ##g') - 2 ))
pdftk ${1}.pdf cat 3-${_endpage} output ${2}.pdf
```

and run it like this:

```
bash  remove-my-4-pages.pdf  myinput.pdf  myoutput.pdf
```

Just make sure that the `pdfinfo` and `pdftk` utilities are in your $PATH environment variable. Otherwise the script will not run. If you installed these utilities from MacPorts, you can put the followng line into your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Combine PDFs](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/CombinePDFs30.shtml)

...is a tool that does this task very fast and simple. It costs $30 in the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/combine-pdfs/id411902389?mt=12&affId=1271297&ign-mpt=uo%3D4), but you can still download the **[completely free version 3.0](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/CombinePDFs30.shtml)** on their website.

The free version **3.0**<sup>1</sup> is already several years old, but I've been using it in Lion without problems. Here's how you do your task very simply explained:

[image]

<sub><sup>1</sup> - note: you'll find also version 4.1 and 4.0 offered as a download, but they are shareware</sub>