# problem searching for text with in a pdf in iBooks?

Tags: ipad, pdf, books

I have a very long pdf document in iBooks and it won't let me search for text in it. I click the search button, type what I want to search and nothing happens. This happens every time, no matter what I type. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the pdf allows searching ? Did you try searching on another device and did it work ?

Comment: I only have my iPad, no other device to check it on. I'm not sure if it's searchable or not, how do I make it searchable?

Comment: If you don't have a computer to try your PDF it could be difficult to find out if it's searchable. PDFs can have different restrictions - like no printing or no searching; to remove these is often possible but a whole [other story](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50282/14994). If it's not text but images (e.g. from a scan) see [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/76471/14994)